# RowClick and find does not work in Devexpress XtraGrid Sub Levels

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have populated a XtraGrid view with two leves.I can work with main level fine but when I want to find in second level by code or even I add an Event like OnRowClick or sth like that for sublevels it does not work.Does any one has my problems?
for example the name of gridview in sublevel is  GridProperty..this code does not work

```
[C#]
GridProperty.ApplyFindFilter(bar_edit_search.EditValue.ToString());
```

or even events does not fire

```
[C#]
private void GridProperty_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e){}
```

Here is how I populate my gridview

```
 string owner = "SELECT [OBJECTID],[Name] ,[Family] ,[Father] ,[shenasname],[Dftarche] ,[Birthday] ,[education] ,[home_address] ,[farm_address] ,[ensurance] ,[phone] ,[home_number] ,[owner_id],[sodor] ,[shahr],[bakhsh]  ,[dehestan]   ,[rosta]    ,[kodPosti] FROM [dbo].[OWNER]";
        string strConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.land_gisConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(owner, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
         dsMain = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dsMain, "First Table");
        dsMain.Tables.Add(iFeatureSet.DataTable.Copy());
        adapter.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("املاک شخصی", dsMain.Tables["First Table"].Columns["owner_id"], dsMain.Tables["Table1"].Columns["owner_ID"]);
        dsMain.Relations.Add(newRelation);

        }

        GridAttrebuteTable.DataSource = dsMain.Tables[0];

        GridAttrebuteTable.ForceInitialize();
        GridOwners.Columns["shahr"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["bakhsh"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["dehestan"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["rosta"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["kodPosti"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["sodor"].Visible = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["sodor"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["shahr"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["bakhsh"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["dehestan"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;
        GridOwners.Columns["rosta"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;

        GridOwners.Columns["kodPosti"].OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide = false;
        SplashScreenManager.CloseForm();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems with sublevels. You must check the following:
0. For [`ColumnView.ApplyFindFilter`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ApplyFindFiltertopic) method check the [`ColumnView.OptionsFind.FindFilterColumns`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsFind_FindFilterColumnstopic) property. According to documentation:

> If the FindFilterColumns property is set to "*", the Find Panel
>   performs searches against all visible columns.
>
> To explicitly specify search columns, set the FindFilterColumns
>   property to a string consisting of the corresponding field names
>   delimited by a semicolon (without space characters):
>   "Name;Value;Description".

So, if your `FindFilterColumn` property is set to wrong value then `ApplyFindFilter` method will not work.
1. For [`GridView.RowClick`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowClicktopic) event according to documentation:

> The RowClick event will not fire when clicking on a row cell, if data
>   editing is enabled and the ColumnViewOptionsBehavior.EditorShowMode
>   property is set to MouseDown (and to Default if multiple row selection
>   is disabled).

So, check your [`ColumnView.OptionsBehavior.EditorShowMode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsBehavior_EditorShowModetopic) property and set it to [`EditorShowMode.Click`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressUtilsEditorShowModeEnumtopic).
2. Check the [`GridLevelNode.RelationName`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridLevelNode_RelationNametopic). It must be equal to `RelationName` in your underlying `DataSource`:

```cs
DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("املاک شخصی", dsMain.Tables["First Table"].Columns["owner_id"], dsMain.Tables["Table1"].Columns["owner_ID"]);

//...

gridControl.LevelTree.Nodes[0].RelationName = "املاک شخصی";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I checked all things that you said and all of them is fine.I think sth is wrong with gridview because my codes work fine when I populate them in the main level.this code also does not work..'GridProperty.StartIncrementalSearch(serchingFor);
                        GridProperty.StopIncrementalSearch();' is there any cast or sth like that?Why Do events does not fire at all while editting is disabled :(

Comment: I think I found the problem,why the column list in gridview is empty while it is populated?How can I get the secound levels Events by code?I think I should add Events by code because I populate gridview by code.I updated my question now

Comment: I set Optionbehavior.Editable=false in designer

Comment: I think I should get the sublevel and add Event to it,Because number of columns in my gridview which name is gridproperty is 0 while my gridview has populated with 21 columns.I think I am working with wrong gridview or sth like that

Comment: @MajidHojati Check the node `RelationName` for your level in your `LevelTree`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: What does `RelationName ` do?How Can I use it to get level 2 of gridview and work with its events ?

Comment: @MajidHojati Use `gridControl.LevelTree.Nodes` property to get all levels. For example: `gridControl.LevelTree.Nodes[0].RelationName = "املاک شخصی";`

Comment: Thanks for your help.Can I cast it as a gridview and add Events to is of find in it?

Comment: @MajidHojati You can cast [`GridLevelNode.LevelTemplate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridLevelNode_LevelTemplatetopic) property to `GridView`: `var gridView = gridControl.LevelTree.Nodes[0].LevelTemplate as GridView`.

Comment: Thank your for your help.It works and Events now fires but When I use this code I get `var gridView = GridAttrebuteTable.LevelTree.Nodes[0].LevelTemplate as GridView;
                  string a = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue(gridView.Columns[0]).ToString().TrimEnd();` object refrence is null error.Where do you think I am wrong?

Comment: @MajidHojati It seems that  `gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue(gridView.Columns[0])` is null, so check it before converting `ToString()`: `var value = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue(gridView.Columns[0]); if (value != null) string a = value.ToString().TrimEnd();`

Comment: Yes..You know I cast sender to a gridview and it worked.Thanks a lot for your time and great help